# $\sup\limits_{\phi} \int_{[0,1] } \log \phi = \int_{[0,1]} \log f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let's say we have a measurable function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow (0, \infty)$.  Approximate $f$ from below by a simple function $\phi$, with $\phi(x) > 0$ for all $x$.  Then $$\int f = \sup\limits_{\phi} \int \phi$$ My question: is it also true that $$\sup\limits_{\phi} \int \ln \phi = \int \ln f\space?$$ I believe this is at least true when $f(x) > 1$ for all $x$ (in which case we can replace the condition $\phi(x) > 0$ with $\phi(x) > 1$).  In this case, $\log f > 0$, and $\int \log f$ is the supremum of all integrals $\int \psi$, where $\psi$ is a positive valued simple function which $\leq \log f$.    But the set of all such $\psi$ coincides exactly with the set of $\log \phi$, where $\phi$ is a simple function with $1 \leq \phi \leq f$.  This is because any such $\phi$ is equal to $$\sum\limits  a_i \chi E_i$$ with $a_i = \log e^{a_i}$.

Comment: For simple functions, you need that $f$ is bounded away from $0$, otherwise there is no simple function $\leqslant \log f$, or, if you allow the value $-\infty$ for simple functions, must attain the value $-\infty$ on a set of positive measure. If you allow countable "linear combinations" of characteristic functions, it works also if $f$ is not bounded away from $0$, if at least one of $(\log f)^+$ and $(\log f)^-$ has finite integral.

Comment: "Approximate $f$ from below by a simple function $\phi$, with $\phi(x) >0$." I don't think you can have both "from below" and "$\phi(x) > 0$". Try $f(0) = 1; f(x) = x$ on $(0,1]$, there is no simple function below $f$ that only takes (finitely many) positive values. Thus you are taking the sup of an empty set.

Comment: I think its true when you approximate from below by a monotonically increasing sequence of simple functions, say $(\phi_n)$, because you have $\lim_n \int \phi_n \to \int f$ by monotone convergence theorem and when you have a monotonically increasing sequence the supremum coincides with the limit.  Then the statement holds from the previous reasoning and the continuity of the logarithm.